# How to apply the window function when finding autocorrelation?

Tags: autocorrelation

I want to get frequencies from amplitudes and I'm following Chap 5.1.1 from [*Speech Signal Processing by Praat*](https://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/david/LOT/sspbook.pdf.)
[image: Apply window function and find autocorrelation]
As the in pictures, I will multiply the signal $s(t)$ with the Hanning window $w(t)$, find its normalized autocorrelation $r_a(\tau)$, and divide by $r_w(\tau)$, which is the normalized autocorrelation of $w(t)$. In the end, I will get the corrected autocorrelations $r(\tau)$.
I understand that diving $r_w$ should somehow rescale $r_a$, but the $r_w$ I got takes negative value, and $r$ gets large where $r_w$ is close to zero. How can I get an $r_w$ as in the picture?

Below are my codes to get $r_w$:

```
def serial_cov(wave:List[int], lag:int)  -> int:
"""
Returns covariance of a signal with a lagged version of itself
"""
global WINDOW_LEN
n=len(wave)
y1=wave[lag:]
y2=wave[0:WINDOW_LEN - lag]
num = float(np.cov(y1,y2,bias=True)[0,1])   
return num

hann = np.hanning(WINDOW_LEN) 
plt.plot(hann) 
plt.title("Hann window amplitude") 
plt.show() 
r0_hann = float(np.cov(hann, hann, bias = True)[0,0])
hann_autocorr = []
for i in range(MAX_LAG+1):
    ri_hann = serial_cov(hann,i)
    hann_autocorr.append(ri_hann/r0_hann)
```